# Get posts from 2 or more categories

Tags: categories

I'm trying to get posts from 2 or more categories, so far I discovered:

```
$args = array( 
    'category__in'=>array( implode(ot_get_option("beautiful_categories"), ",")  )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I'm using OptionTree and that will return categories ids with "," between them.
and then I get post with while loop, but it just return posts of first category.

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that was my error, OptionTree for this input type(radio in my case) itself returns an array and we don't need to convert it. and category__in needs an array so i just change it to:

```
$args = array( 
    'category__in' => ot_get_option( 'beautiful_categories' )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The 'category__in' parameter accepts an array. You're giving it a string of comma-separated values. Also, you need to use `explode()` instead of `implode()`. `implode()` is for joining array elements with a string, while `explode()` is for splitting a string by another string. Try this instead:

```
$args = array( 
    'category__in' => array( explode( ot_get_option( 'beautiful_categories' ), ',' ) ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```